# Query a json string SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the hardest time querying a json string. This is my string:

```
{
   "Microsoft.Resources":{
      "resourceUri":"/subscriptions/123subscription123/resourceGroups/123resourcegroup123/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/123storagaccount123",
      "location":"euwest"
   }
}
```

I just need the following json fields into columns:

- resourceUri
- Location

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(I.value, '$.resourceUri') as resourceUri
,      JSON_VALUE(C.value, '$.Location') as Location
FROM   OPENJSON(InstanceData, N'lax $.Microsoft.Resources') I
CROSS 
APPLY  OPENJSON(I.value, N'lax $.fields.resourceUri') C
```

But I get no result.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having a hard time because the name `Microsoft.Resources` contains a period and thus must be quoted in order to be used in paths, but beyond that it's nothing complicated:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{
   "Microsoft.Resources":{
      "resourceUri":"/subscriptions/123subscription123/resourceGroups/123resourcegroup123/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/123storagaccount123",
      "location":"euwest"
   }
}'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$."Microsoft.Resources"')
WITH (
    [resourceUri] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [location] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, that works brilliant! Indeed, the issues was the doublequotes.